# To check if string contains specific number or not

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns in two different tables.
First column is number like `0493484402` and second column is audit_detail like `'addr_mastersubscription has changed from 32488141893 to 32488141973'`.

Audit detail column may have different type of string other than above. I have to check only in above type mentioned strings

I have to check whether first column value is present or not in second column at position of Second number.

If the number is not present I need that number as output

I am using oracel SQL developer

Second column datatype is clob and there is not comman filed in both table's

First column data type is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col2, ' to ' || col1 || '$');
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Can you please explain me the above expression

Comment: @Dhanshri `REGEXP_LIKE` compares the second column against the regex ` to col1$`.  That is, it checks if the second column ends in ` to col1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the two conditions then you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `REGEXP_LIKE` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(SECOND_COLUMN, '^addr_mastersubscription has changed from [0-9]+ to [0-9]+$')
AND TO_NUMBER(FIRST_COLUMN) = TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SECOND_COLUMN,'[0-9]+$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

Sample data (lines #1 - 9) contain additional `ID` column (unless you're planning to do cross join between those two tables) which is used to join `taba` and `tabb`.

`regexp_substr` looks for the second number in `tabb`'s `col` column, which is compared to `taba.col`. I displayed whether it exists there or not; you can display whatever you want.

Query you might need begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with
  2  taba (id, col) as
  3    (select 1, '0493484402' from dual union all
  4     select 2, '012345'     from dual
  5    ),
  6  tabb (id, col) as
  7    (select 1, 'addr_mastersubscription has changed from 32488141893 to 32488141973' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'nothing changed from 098776 to 012345'                               from dual
  9    )
 10  --
 11  select a.id,
 12         case when a.col = regexp_substr(b.col, '\d+', 1, 2) then a.col || ' exists in tabb'
 13              else a.col || ' does not exist in tabb'
 14         end result
 15  from taba a join tabb b on a.id = b.id;

        ID RESULT
---------- ---------------------------------
         1 0493484402 does not exist in tabb
         2 012345 exists in tabb

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTR()`, names itself defines `in string` where we can check if a particular string is available in the respective column.

Please use below query,

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on (instr(t1.first_column, t2.second_column) = 0);
```

`instr(t1.first_column, t2.second_column) = 0` This condition provides you unmatching columns

`instr(t1.first_column, t2.second_column) > 0` This condition provides you matching strings